# Azure AD B2C custom policy for generic OpenID Connect IDP crashing with server error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We are making a website using ASP.NET 6.0.408.
For authentication/authorization, we use Azure AD B2C custom policies.
We are now trying to make a custom policy that connect to an external identity provider over OpenID Connect. We followed [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-generic-openid-connect?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) but running the resulting policy causes a server error on the AAD B2C side.
[image]

Unfortunately, not the most informative error message.

Here's the relevant technical profile:

```
<ClaimsProvider>
    <DisplayName>{Display name}</DisplayName>
    <TechnicalProfiles>

        <TechnicalProfile Id="{Technical Profile}">
            <DisplayName>{Technical Profile}</DisplayName>
            <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect"/>
            <Metadata>
                <Item Key="METADATA">{METADATA endpoint}</Item>
                <Item Key="client_id">{Our client id}</Item>
                <Item Key="response_types">code</Item>
                <Item Key="scope">openid profile</Item>
                <Item Key="response_mode">form_post</Item>
                <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
                <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
            </Metadata>
            <CryptographicKeys>
                <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_ClientSecret" />
            </CryptographicKeys>
            <OutputClaims>
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="oid"/>
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" PartnerClaimType="tid"/>
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="email" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" PartnerClaimType="iss" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="oid"/>
            </OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaimsTransformations>
                <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName"/>
                <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName"/>
                <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId"/>
                <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId"/>
            </OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin"/>
        </TechnicalProfile>

    </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

and user journey:

```
<UserJourney Id="{User journey}">
    <OrchestrationSteps>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
            <ClaimsProviderSelections>
                <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="SigninExchange" />
            </ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="SigninExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="{Technical profile}" />
            </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when in the token. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
            <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
            </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
    </OrchestrationSteps>
</UserJourney>
```

and relying party policy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<TrustFrameworkPolicy
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06"
    PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0"
    TenantId="yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com"
    PolicyId="B2C_1A_Policy"
    PublicPolicyUri="http://yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_Policy">

<BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions</PolicyId>
</BasePolicy>

<RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="{User journey}" />
    <Endpoints>
        <!--points to refresh token journey when app makes refresh token request-->
        <Endpoint Id="Token" UserJourneyReferenceId="RedeemRefreshToken" />
    </Endpoints>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
        <DisplayName>Policy profile</DisplayName>
        <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
        <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" />
        </OutputClaims>
        <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
</RelyingParty>
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```

The error does not come from the METADATA endpoint or client_id or client_secret being wrong because we used the same in a user flow which works great.

We also tried with `response_types` set to `id_token`, but we get the same error.

No errors when uploading the XML files in Azure AD B2C.

We wonder if the problem may be that some output claims aren't supported by the external identity provider, but if it was the case, it wouldn't fail like that. I wouldn't expect it to fail, actually, just have some output claims empty. But at least, if it were to fail, it would fail later on in the journey, after submitting credentials in the signin form. But the form doesn't even show up here. It crashes from the beginning.

Question: Any idea about the source of the error, and a solution to solve it?

PS:

- We don't have an Azure Application Insights subscription, and can't afford one. So not possible to use it for (perhaps) better error messages.